# I need to get the opportunity record type.name in APEX trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Why does the following generate an error:

> Invalid field recordTypeID for SObject Opportunity

```
trigger OnOpportunity on Opportunity(before update){

     Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Opportunity.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

     for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){

          if(rt_map.get(opp.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('YOUR VALUE')){
               //Do your stuff
          }

     }


}
```

Comment: Do you actually have record types defined on Opportunity?

Comment: try this opp.get('recordTypeID') instead of opp.recordTypeID

Answer (score 2):

This error will occur if you don't have any RecordTypes defined in the metadata for `Opportunity`. I reproduced the exact error in my Dev Edition (that doesn't have any RecordTypes defined on Opportunity).

Salesforce is pretty clever (or aggravating, depending on your point of view) in that standard fields that are enabled by other metadata don't surface to the SObject until such enablement is done. Hence these standard fields fields are unavailable to be used in formula fields, validation rules, and apex/visualforce.

The two best examples of this that come to mind are:

- RecordTypeId  `// no recordtypes on sobject, no field`
- CurrencyIsoCode `// no multi currency, no currencyIsoCode field`

The reasons for this are obvious, why confuse a point-and-click admin with a standard field that isn't relevant given other metadata setup.